# How to avoid system kills when combining frames into one video

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, video

I was using python to combine 5576 images into one video at 30 fps.

I tried many codes posted on the internet but however I always get this error.

```
Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
```

which I looked into the operating system was killing my process.

I'm using ubuntu, pycharm, python3.8 64-bit.

```
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
import re


#Natural key for natural sort
def atoi(text):
    return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text

def natural_keys(text):
    return [ atoi(c) for c in re.split(r'(\d+)', text) ]

li = []
for filename in glob.glob('det/*.jpg'):
    li.append(filename)

li.sort(key=natural_keys)

img_array = []
for filename in li:
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    height, width, layers = img.shape
    size = (width, height)
    img_array.append(img)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print(f"Frame #{filename}")

out = cv2.VideoWriter('Video/label_vid.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 30, size)

for i in range(len(img_array)):
    out.write(img_array[i])
out.release()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the process must be crashing in the `for filename in li:img = cv2.imread(filename)`. What you are trying to do here is to read 5K images using `cv2.imread()`. Let's assume that size of a single image is 1MB in memory(this is different from the disk size), then the above process would be holding up 5GB of memory. What I would recommend in this scenario is that, instead of reading all the images and storing them in `img_array.append(img)`, we should encode the frames directly to the video stream as:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('Video/label_vid.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 30, size)

for filename in li:
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    out.write(img)
out.release()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation and clarification of the code.

Comment: I searched for answers for two days. :D